# Get linearly spread array of dates between two dates, given count of desired dates - javascript, d3.js, moment.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, momentjs

Let's say I have dates:

`Mon Mar 31 2014 05:42:35 GMT+0200 (CEST)`

`Wed Sep 02 2015 10:29:38 GMT+0200 (CEST)`

and `totalNumberOfDates = 37;`

I'd like to get array of 37 dates (first and last date should be those above), which are exactly linearly spread between given dates.

I'd appreciate elegant solution in D3.js or moment.js

Comment: Set a variable to be a `Date` object with the value of the first date. Loop 35 times, adding 37 days to that variable each time. If you are having issues, post your code here and people can help you.

Comment: I think you misunderstood question. Dates shouldn't be spread by 37 days. .. It should return array of 35 Date objects, which are exactly linearly spread in between given 2 date objects

Comment: Oh... what's the stepSize then?

Comment: Anyway, if we can ignore stepSize (I'm not sure what it is), then all you need to do is find out the number of days for each 'step'. So, in pseudo code: `d1 = first date`, `d2 = second date`, `total_days = d2 - d1` and finally `days_per_step = total_days / 35`.

Now you can follow my instructions from the first comment, using days_per_step instead of 37.

Comment: all right, stepSize name might be a bit misleading. It's a number of date objects it should return in result. including given first and last date object

Comment: Yeah, stepSize is a terrible name for that. :) I'd go with totalNumberOfDates, though honestly if you're gonna say 35 days in between, then there's no need to tell us about 37 total. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
function getDateRange(startDate, endDate, steps)
{
    var stepSize = (endDate - startDate) / steps;
    return d3.range(steps + 1).map(function(i){ return moment(startDate).add(stepSize * i, 'ms').toDate() });
}
```

where `startDate` and `endDate` are **Date** objects.

Note that the function will return an array with length `steps+1`. Because from my point of view this is logical. If for example you want *one step* from 12 to 14 oclock I would expect the result to be something like `[12oclock, 14oclock]`.

Comment: Seems like exactly what I was searching for. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

```js
    var getMySpecialDates = function(d1,d2,r){
    d1 =  new Date(d1);
    d2 =  new Date(d2);
    var time = (d2.getTime()-d1.getTime())/(r);
    time = Math.floor(time);
    var temp = d1;
    var result = new Array()
    while(temp.getTime()<=(d2.getTime())){
        var f  = new Date(temp);
          result.push(f);
          temp.setTime(temp.getTime()+time);
          }
    return result;
}
var dates = getMySpecialDates("Mon Mar 31 2014 05:42:35 GMT+0200 (CEST)", "Wed Sep 02 2015 10:29:38 GMT+0200 (CEST)", 37);
console.log("Total Dates: " + dates.length);
for(var i=0;i<dates.length;i++){
console.log((dates[i]).toString());
}
```